# on screen android animation

Tags: android, android-animation, sprite

I am new to Android, creating an Android application that have animations that will be displayed on the main screen (as in desktop) and I am planning to use sprites for this. But I don't know how to display the animation in the desktop. Please suggest if there is any better method. I am planning to create a train that runs around the desktop.Can any one help?

Comment: create it as normal activity and made all of its background transparent. Then apply your animation and see...!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, also give [ask] a read.

Comment: please make your question more clear. Add code details, reference image, something for us to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to run activity with Transparent background.The following code is used to be a current window with Transparent background.In manifest file,

```
<activity
            android:name=".First"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If you want to floating that window :

```
 <activity
            android:name="Second"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.Floating" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Actually this is used for show two activities in one screen in my example...